# Weird problem when binding a dynamic list

Tags: java, spring, collections, spring-mvc, constructor

**INITIAL QUESTION (UPDATED BELOW)**

I'm using an `AutoPopulatingList` list to instatiate an object invoking a constructor with some parameters. Something like the code below. I had used it before without any problems but I can't get it working now.

```
public class Tree {
    ...
    private List<Node> nodes = new AutoPopulatingList<Node>(new ElementFactory<Node>() {
        @Override
        public Node createElement(final int index) throws ElementInstantiationException {
             //call custom controller
             return new Node(index, ...other params);
        }       
    });
    ...
    //getters & setters
}
```

The object is mapped in a controller as a model attribute param (`@ModelAttribute Tree`). So I send in the form values like:

```
nodes[0].field1 = some value
nodes[1].field2 = other value
```

But when I send these parameters spring cannot instantiate the `Node` object because it's looking for a constructor without params for `Node` object, and it throws an Exception like the following:

> org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'nodes' of bean class [...Node]: Could not instantiate property type [...Node] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: ...Node.()

If I add a constructor without params to `Node` class there is no error, but when I send `nodes[0]` it is invoked `Node()` instead of using the `ElementFactory` provided.

The weird thing is that if I do in the controller `treeObject.getNodes().get(0)`, the constructor invoked is the one with params (as it should be).

I'm using Spring 3.0.4.RELEASE.

Does anybody knows why can this be happening? Can this be a bug?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

I have build a custom implementation of a List similar to AutoPopulatingList to check if this was a problem of AutoPopulatingList, but it happens the same behaviour.
The implementation just overrides:

```
public Node get(int index) {
    //here just creates the object it it doesn't exist in the position
}
```

So the problem is why when I do in a controller:

```
public String controllerMethod(
@ModelAttribute Tree tree, BindingResult result, Model model){
     ...
}
```

and I send nodes[0].something as there isn't any object in the position 0 of index it has to instance the object. But the problem is that it is invoked Node() constructor before invoking tree.get(0). So, Why does Spring invokes the default constructor? How can I force it to use tree.get(0) to instance the object instead of Node()?

Comment: You told: "I had used it before without any problems but I can't get it working now." - what have you changed?

Comment: For me it looks like, if someone removes the node list from Tree before Spring starts populating it.

Comment: @Ralph I have only changed the Spring version (though it was Spring 3 too) and obviously the object because I used it in other projects. But I haven't changed the way I use it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've solved it by disabling the autogrownestedpaths in the binder, so this allows Autopopulating list will take care of auto-growing with its own factory.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);
}
```